# Is there way to create "plain text" from docx with text highlight programmatically

Tags: parsing, document, pandoc

I've tried pandoc to create rst and latex documents that would include text highlight. The higlighted text contains all necessary info that I need parse.

Is there a way to do it with pandoc or should I start looking something else?

Also the solution should be support cli tools.

Comment: what do you mean with "text highlight"? see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I mean this MS Office Word feature https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Apply-or-remove-highlighting-1747d808-6db7-4d49-86ac-1f0c3cc87e2e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, pandoc's document model doesn't include pen-marker kind of highlighting, only semantic [*emphasis*](http://pandoc.org/README.html#inline-formatting). You would need to post-process the generated file.